# Where is the score function in scikit-learn classifiers located?

Tags: python, function, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When running cross-validation within `scikit-learn`, all classifiers would have a factory function `score()` which I can easily check the accuracy of the classifier, e.g. from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn import cross_validation
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> from sklearn import svm

>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> iris.data.shape, iris.target.shape
((150, 4), (150,))
>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
...     iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

>>> X_train.shape, y_train.shape
((90, 4), (90,))
>>> X_test.shape, y_test.shape
((60, 4), (60,))

>>> clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)
>>> clf.score(X_test, y_test)                           
0.96...
```

After digging into the github repo for `scikit-learn`, I still can't figure out where is the function for the `clf.score()` function.

There is this link but it doesn't contain the `score()`, https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/classes.py

**Where is the `score()` function for `sklearn` classifiers located?**

I could [implement my own score function easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689721/calculating-precision-recall-and-f-score-in-one-pass-python), but the aim is to build my library so that it is coherent with the `sklearn` classifiers, *not to come up with my own scoring function* =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default `score()` method for scikit-learn classifiers is the accuracy score, and is [defined in the `ClassifierMixin` class](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L325). This mixin is a parent class of most (all?) of scikit-learn's built-in classifiers.

If you're writing your own classifier, I would suggest inheriting from this mixin and `BaseEstimator` as well, so that you'll get the scoring and other features for your model automatically.